# Select a single column across an entire database

Tags: sql

I have database (couple hundred tables) that all contains a specific column called `LastReplicationDate`. This column name is always the same in each table, and is always the same value within each table.

Is it possible to write a query that gets the distinct value of this column assigned to each table in my database without having to select each table via a union query?

Comment: If there is a valid way, why do you want another? I just would add a `top 1`, or `where rownum=1` or `limit 1` (you don't specify the database you are using) in this `UNION`, if it's true that it has always the same value within each table

Comment: Several decades ago when I was a newish programmer I learned the hard way that it is never wise to say something is impossible, but I'm pretty confident here that this is impossible without UNION.

Comment: You could write a stored procedure that dynamically generates the query for each table, executes it and saves the result each time

Comment: I'd prefer not to have to specify each unique table every single time. I'm hoping there's a more elegant way to do this.